# Test Data not showing in All Steps page in Cluecumber report plugin

Tags: automation, cucumber, report, reporting, bdd

I am generating the cluecumber report. When ever the report is generated , in the All Steps page the test data is not getting populated rather the steps are showing empty angular brackets like {}.

**The test case is written as -**

```
 
@Regression
  Scenario: Create a new Modifiers
    Given item image is clicked
    When modifiers option is selected
    And modifier is created as **"ModifierName"**
    And enter modifier option and modifier price as **"Mod"** and **"3.50"** respectively
    And hit save
    Then verify modifier is created as **"ModifierName"**
```

**
See the below image for how it is generating now.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lohkb.png)

pom file looks like this-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7gCr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj2L3.png)

I wish test data passed in feature file to appear in steps while report is generated in All Steps Page and no {} empty brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The all steps page shows which step implementations are used in which scenarios. This is independent of parameter values.

In the scenario details you see the data you need since here the steps are used with concrete values.